# D3 Map - Context Menu - not able to update path attributes

Tags: d3.js

Hi I am trying to add markers, (or changing fill property is also fine) of the D3 map based on Context menu selection. I was referring to the examples at http://jsfiddle.net/1mo3vmja/2/, (pasting the code below) but after clicking the context menu item , I am not able to get the d3 element which invoked the context menu. Can someone help?

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Grape"];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

var circle = svgContainer
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 30)
    .attr("cy", 30)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .on('contextmenu', function(d,i) {
          // create the div element that will hold the context menu
          d3.selectAll('.context-menu').data([1])
            .enter()
            .append('div')
            .attr('class', 'context-menu');
          // close menu
          d3.select('body').on('click.context-menu', function() {
            d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
          });
          // this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
          d3.selectAll('.context-menu')
            .html('')
            .append('ul')
            .selectAll('li')
              .data(fruits).enter()
              .append('li')

          .on('click' , function(d) { console.log(d); return d; })


              .text(function(d) { return d; });
          d3.select('.context-menu').style('display', 'none');
          // show the context menu
          d3.select('.context-menu')
            .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
            .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
            .style('display', 'block');
          d3.event.preventDefault();
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the element on which you are drawing the context menu something like this:

```
  .on('contextmenu', function(d, i) {
      var me = this;//storing the circle instance inside variable me
```

Now when you select the context menu element you can refer the object `me`.

```
.on('click', function(d) {
  console.log(d, me);
  return d;
})
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/m3q4o78a/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Cyril; this helps.